# Unable to access object properties from the same class but different method in C#

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am unable to access the properties of the object student1 that has been created in the Main() method of the Program class in the method ClassOperations() of the same class. I keep getting

> error CS0103: The name 'student1' does not exist in the current
>   context

```
using System;

namespace Trials
{
    public class Students
    {
      public int maths;
      public int science;
      public int english;
      public int secondLang;
      public int socialScience;
      public string name;

      public Students(int[] inputMarks)
      {
        maths = inputMarks[0];
        science = inputMarks[1];
        english = inputMarks[2];
        secondLang = inputMarks[3];
        socialScience = inputMarks[4];
      }
    }

    public class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
            string inputName = Console.ReadLine();
            int[] marks = new int[5];

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the maths marks: ");
            marks[0] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Science marks: ");
            marks[1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the English marks: ");
            marks[2] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Second language marks: ");
            marks[3] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Social Science marks: ");
            marks[4] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Students student1 = new Students(marks);

            student1.name = inputName;
            ClassOperations();
        }

      static void ClassOperations()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Enter input :");
          int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

          switch (input)
          {
            case 1:
              Console.WriteLine(student1.name);
              break;
            case 2:
              Console.WriteLine(student1.maths);
              break;
            case 3:
              Console.WriteLine(student1.science);
              break;
            case 4:
              Console.WriteLine(student1.english);
              break;
            case 5:
              Console.WriteLine(student1.secondLang);
              break;
            case 6:
              Console.WriteLine(student1.socialScience);
              break;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this example, you need to store the value in a static property or field *or* pass it as a parameter to your method. Local variables within one method are not accessible within other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem: local variables (`student1`) declared in a method (`Main`) are not accessible within other methods (`ClassOperations`, the current context). You have several options:

- (static) property
- (static) field
- method parameter

In this example, the "best" option is to pass your `student1` variable as a parameter to the `ClassOperations` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    // setup elided
    Students student1 = new Students(marks);
    student1.name = inputName;  
    // pass as parameter    
    ClassOperations(student1);
} 

static void ClassOperations(Students student) {
    // access value via new name "student" 
    Console.WriteLine(student.name);
}
```

Based on your comments, here is what the alternative with a field *could* look like:

```
static Students student; //static field 
static void Main(string[] args) {
    // setup elided
    // initialize static field 
    student = new Students(marks);
    student.name = inputName;  
    ClassOperations();
} 

static void ClassOperations() {
    // access value via static field "student" 
    Console.WriteLine(student.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did realize this way of getting the code to work. However, I was hoping for another way of doing it (without passing student1 as a parameter). Since, I am only just a beginner with C#, I am not familiar with the first two methods that you mentioned : (static) property and (static) field. A little more context on those two other methods would be really helpful. I would be grateful if you could direct me to some resources with this regard or provide an example. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The updated answer is exactly what I hoped for. I got very close to the exact code you provided but I missed the static modifier when declaring the field.